# Is mounting same NFS share read-write on one host and read-only on other(s) okay?

Tags: backup, nfs

I have a workstation that `rw`-mounts an NFS share from a service provider. I also have another server whose entire file system is already backed up to a remote site. Can I add the NFS share to this backup (i.e. keep an extra backup in additional to the one the service provider already keeps) by `ro`-mounting the same NFS share on my server?

In other words, is mounting the same NFS share multiple times okay (1 x `rw` + n times `ro`) in terms of data consistency? I guess so, but I want to be sure, because this is for backup purposes. Are there any relevant version dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

exporting both read-only and read-write is technically OK, from [man 5 exports](https://linux.die.net/man/5/exports)

```
 /               master(rw) trusty(rw,no_root_squash)
```

Comment: however, "extra backup" sounds like an XY-problem, you can't relay on multiple backup "just in case"

Comment: Can you please clarify: So it's technically OK to mount the same NFS share on two different hosts (with `rw` and `ro` respectively) *at the same time*. Also, I do not quite get the gist of your comment: *you can't relay on multiple backup "just in case"*.